# Parsing of SSL/TLS fields.

Tags: c, ssl, tls1.2

I am doing a raw parsing of SSL/TLS packets using libpcap. How do I figure out how many TLS Records are present in the packet. Which field can give me that information?

Answer (score 0):

Each TLS record has a fixed format with some fixed length parts and a single variable length part - which is prefixed by the length of this part. See [RFC 5246 "Record Layer"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2) for the exact details. The data stream consists of a number of such TLS records one after each other with no other data in between. This means one can find out where a TLS record ends and the next one starts.

But one cannot find out up-front how many TLS records are in a packet. Also packet boundaries don't need to be record boundaries. This means a single TLS record can span multiple packets, a packet can contain multiple TLS records or something in between like one full TLS record plus a bit of the next TLS record contained in one record and the rest of the second TLS record spread over the following packets.